# Does npm '-g' alias directly to '--global' or are there differences?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I can see in the [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) that -g and --global both put us in 'global mode' for installing a package.

Does -g just alias directly to --global?
Or are there differences that I should be aware of?

Bonus question: Can I view the code directly to learn how to answer these questions for myself? Perhaps something like a project.json "scripts" where these aliases exist?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The -g or --global argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally. See npm-folders.

Without reviewing the [sources](https://github.com/npm/npm) I'd go for the alias theory. When it comes to the bonus question: of cause you can have a look at the sources. 
There is a related parameter with different behaviour:

> The --global-style argument will cause npm to install the package into your local node_modules folder with the same layout it uses with the global node_modules folder. Only your direct dependencies will show in node_modules and everything they depend on will be flattened in their node_modules folders. This obviously will eliminate some deduping.